# Need to add caption for picture. It just doesnt work with that obvious way. LaTex

Tags: floats, captions, baposter

```
\headerbox {Anomaly Detection}{name=problem,column=0,below=boxname1}{
 
 \textbf{Anomaly detection} is a subset of data processing and also the study of sorting and classifying normal data from abnormal
data.
\\ \textbf{An anomaly}(also known as an outlier) is anything unusual, odd, abnormal, strange, or
difficult to categorize. In statistics, this term is a data point that is noticeably different
from previous observations. An outlier may be the \textbf{consequence of experimental mistake}
.An outlier might indicate an intriguing opportunity
but can also result in significant issues with statistical analysis

\centering  \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{images/anomaly.png}


}
```

I tried:

```
\headerbox {Anomaly Detection}{name=problem,column=0,below=boxname1}{
 
 \textbf{Anomaly detection} is a subset of data processing and also the study of sorting and classifying normal data from abnormal
data.
\\ \textbf{An anomaly}(also known as an outlier) is anything unusual, odd, abnormal, strange, or
difficult to categorize. In statistics, this term is a data point that is noticeably different
from previous observations. An outlier may be the \textbf{consequence of experimental mistake}
.An outlier might indicate an intriguing opportunity
but can also result in significant issues with statistical analysis

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{images/anomaly.png}
\caption{Figure 1: Anomaly Detection Process Flow}
\label{fig:anomaly_detection}
\end{figure}


}
```

and many other ways. it just does nothing: I want[image: I want to add the red text in the red circle]

I cant see Figure1: Anomaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{caption}` to the preamble
and use `\captionof{figure}{<text>}` to make the figure caption.

[image: a]

```
\headerbox{Problem}{name=problem,column=0,row=0}{
 \textbf{Anomaly detection} is a subset of data processing and also the study of sorting and classifying normal data from abnormal  data.   \\ 
 \textbf{An anomaly}(also known as an outlier) is anything unusual, odd, abnormal, strange, or
difficult to categorize. In statistics, this term is a data point that is noticeably different
from previous observations. An outlier may be the \textbf{consequence of experimental mistake}. An outlier might indicate an intriguing opportunity but can also result in significant issues with statistical analysis.

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.55\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{Anomaly Detection Process Flow}\label{fig:anomaly_detection}
\end{center}    
}
```

The environment `center` will add some space before and after the figure.

(Avoid using `\begin{figure}[h]` to put the image there. It is not necessary at all. I don't think you want to have images floating around on a poster.)

Comment: thank you, i totally forgot about these packages haha. :)